# Create Multiple File Upload Metabox in Wordpress

Tags: custom-field, metabox, post-meta

I am trying to create a metabox to upload multiple files (can be images or files).

Currently I have the upload field and its working fine until the time we press upload and save the data.

The only problem is displaying the files.

Below is my code, I am using to display the metabox:

```
case 'file_list':
                    echo '<input class="cmb_upload_file" type="text" size="36" name="', $field['id'], '" value="" />';
                    echo '<input class="cmb_upload_button button" type="button" value="Upload File" />';
                    echo '<p class="cmb_metabox_description">', $field['desc'], '</p>';
                        $args = array(
                                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                                'numberposts' => null,
                                'post_status' => null,
                                'post_parent' => $post->ID
                            );
                            $attachments = get_posts($args);
                            if ($attachments) {
                                echo '<ul class="attach_list">';
                                foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                                    echo '<li>'.wp_get_attachment_link($attachment->ID, 'thumbnail', 0, 0, 'Download');
                                    echo '<span>';
                                    echo apply_filters('the_title', '&nbsp;'.$attachment->post_title);
                                    echo '</span></li>';
                                }
                                echo '</ul>';
                            }
                        break;
```

1) Currently its displaying me all the files attached to post & I need to display only the files uploaded using this metabox.

2) Need a small thumbnail preview of the file.

Regards.

Comment: Are you using the new media uploader?

Answer (score 1):

question 1

Im not sure how you can do that, But you could try add the image link, and the file path as a meta_post and get the values from there, when you get the values you will only get the files/images from that post uploaded from that metabox.

You can also try custom-fields-to-attachments where you add an ID to only query the files you uploaded from that metabox.

question 2

this code could work.

```
<?php wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, $size, $icon, $attr ); ?>
```